# Game theory - comparing utility

Tags: game-theory

[image]

When we first solve this question, how do we completely eliminate $C$ and give $(q)$ possibility to $A$ and $(1-q)$ to $B$? I understand where the $q$ comes from, but I dont understand how choosing $A$ and $B$ gives a bigger utility. What do you have to compare here?

Comment: For the strategy of 2, it is completely irrelevant if or how likely 1 chooses C. Thus, when 1 chooses C with probability p, the expected gain is $p 6 +(1-p) X$, where X is the expected gain given that 1 never chooses C. Thus, 1 maximizes gain by choosing p=0 if X>6, and p=1 otherwise. It thus suffices to determine X.

Comment: I'm still a little confused - how is the formula 6+(1−) ? is this set C's possibility is  and A, B's possibility is set as (1−)?  Also, we get 6 from the right component of (6,6) right?

Comment: Yes. 1 chooses A with probability $(1-p)q$, B with $(1-p)(1-q)$ and C with $p$ (my definition). I interpret the graph that leaves are labeled (outcome player 1, outcome player 2). It might help to think like this: 1 is offered a game where he can choose only between A and B. 1 however also has the option to reject playing the game, which corresponds to C, in which case he is guaranteed to get 6. Even more intuitive: subtract 6 from all gains. If 1 plays the game (chooses between A and B), he gets X-6. If he doesn't play the game, he gets nothing. There is no point for him to play if X-6<0.

Comment: But if player 1 is guaranteed 6, and has a possibility of getting 0 (A, R), then why would he play? How do we decide from the beginning that (6,6) has less utility? sorry if this sounds dumb.. i'm so confused

Comment: He also has a possibility to get more than 6 (e.g.8 by (A,L). We don't know at the beginning if (6,6) has more or less utility for 1. However,  it is always the best outcome for 2. If possible, 2 will thus try to force 1 to choose C by lowering the gain of choosing A or B below 6. This is e.g. possible by always choosing R (max gain player 1: 5). But anyways, this is not what is asked, since the question implicitly states that p=0...

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure  i understand this correctly, but Player 1 will choose A and B not because he gains more/ less but because he knows that Player 2 will gain less (not 6 but 3, 4, 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109567/discussion-between-engineer-trying-math-and-chrissy-kwon).